# On Scroll Down/Up Show Hide Multiple Elements in a Sequence

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to Show/Hide multiple elements om scroll up and scroll down.

What I need is, when I scroll down and scroll amount is greater than ( **div1** `offset(). top` and less than **div2** `offset().top` ) **div1** should be visible and when scroll amount is greater than ( **div2** `offset(). top` and less than **div3** `offset().top` ) **div2** should be visible instead of **div1** and so on...

I have tried this with no success, Please guide. Thanks!

```js
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
  var st = $(window).scrollTop(),
      dv1 = $('#div1').offset().top - 300,
      dv2 = $('#div2').offset().top - 300,
      dv3 = $('#div3').offset().top - 300,
      dv4 = $('#div4').offset().top - 300;

  if( st > dv1 &&  st < dv2) {
    $('#div1 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 200);
  } else {
    $('#div1 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 200);
  }

  if( st > dv2 &&  st < dv3) {
    $('#div2 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 200);
  } else {
    $('#div2 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 200);
  }
});
```

```css
.divOnFruits{margin-top:78px; font-size:22px; width:168px; display:block; }
.divOnFruits div { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divOnFruits" id="div1">
  <div>At <span class="blueColor">over 3 feet tall,</span> <br> it stands taller <br> than the average <br> 4-year-old.</div>
 </div>
   <div class="divOnFruits" id="div2">
  <div>And it <span class="blueColor">serves <br> more than 200 people </span> – making sure no one walks away hungry!</div>
 </div>
 <div class="divOnFruits" id="div3">
  <div>We use <span class="blueColor"> 6 different types of fruit </span> to build our most bountiful fruit arrangement! (And 8 types in the chocolate dipped version.)</div>
 </div>
 <div class="divOnFruits" id="div4">
  <div>This massively delicious arrangement <span class="blueColor"> <br>weighs in at <br> over 65 lbs.</span></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing minus 300 from your javascript code. Try following code.

```js
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
  var st = $(window).scrollTop(),
      dv1 = $('#div1').offset().top;
      dv2 = $('#div2').offset().top;
      dv3 = $('#div3').offset().top;
      dv4 = $('#div4').offset().top;

  if( st > dv1 &&  st < dv2) {
    $('#div1 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 200);
  } else {
    $('#div1 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 200);
  }

  if( st > dv2 &&  st < dv3) {
    $('#div2 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 200);
  } else {
    $('#div2 div').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 200);
  }
});
```

```css
.divOnFruits{margin-top:78px; font-size:22px; width:168px; display:block; }
.divOnFruits div { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divOnFruits" id="div1">
  <div>At <span class="blueColor">over 3 feet tall,</span> <br> it stands taller <br> than the average <br> 4-year-old.</div>
 </div>
   <div class="divOnFruits" id="div2">
  <div>And it <span class="blueColor">serves <br> more than 200 people </span> – making sure no one walks away hungry!</div>
 </div>
 <div class="divOnFruits" id="div3">
  <div>We use <span class="blueColor"> 6 different types of fruit </span> to build our most bountiful fruit arrangement! (And 8 types in the chocolate dipped version.)</div>
 </div>
 <div class="divOnFruits" id="div4">
  <div>This massively delicious arrangement <span class="blueColor"> <br>weighs in at <br> over 65 lbs.</span></div>
 </div>
```